# Distinguish ssh connections from different origins behind NAT

Tags: linux, ssh, logging, nat

I have a jump server, that many of the clients that connect to it, are sitting behind a NAT, unfortunately, all those clients also uses the same user to connect.

Given I have root access for the jump server and I can configure sshd (and other tools?) as I want, can you think of any technique to distinguish different ssh sessions that came from different origin (node)?

Thanks

Comment: With what goal?

Comment: Get rid of the jump box and use a VPN, IPv6, or both.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, this environment is given and I can't affect how it is used.

Comment: @Sven, I correlate another activity with ssh sessions, and I need to distinguish different origins.

Comment: Then give everyone their own user accounts on the jump box. There is no reason anyone should ever share accounts. This is horrible bad practice.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, that's the obvious and right solution, no body can argue against that, but I don't have the ability to do that.

Comment: You have rejected every possible solution. You will have to get approval for one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I guess enabling only Ipv6 might be possible, but I still hope for something else, even if it is twisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no way to distinguish the same credential for the same user from the same IP address.

Create a user per person. This ties access to their identity, which may be required depending on your compliance environment. And allows other authentication factors like one time passwords from a device they own.

Create a credential per person. Could be a unique ssh key, unique credentials to connect to the VPN, or both.

Use IPv6. While NAT is fine for many use cases, you want to identify per user connections which NAT won't give you. However, you will not know exactly which user with just the IP address unless you control the end point.